# Implementing IFileIsInUse

Tags: winapi, com

I'm trying to implement the `IFileIsUse` COM interface in my Delphi program so that Windows Explorer can show more details about my application when it locks a file.
I based my code on the FileIsUse sample from Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330722%28VS.85%29.aspx) and am up to this:

```
type
  TFileIsInUseImpl = class(TInterfacedObject, IUnknown, IFileIsInUse)
  protected
    function GetAppName(out ppszName: LPWSTR) : HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetUsage(out pfut : FILE_USAGE_TYPE) : HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetCapabilities(out pdwCapFlags : DWORD) : HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetSwitchToHWND(out phwnd : HWND) : HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CloseFile() : HRESULT; stdcall;
  public
    constructor Create(const AFileName: string);
  end;

procedure RegisterFileIsInUse(const AFileName: string);
var
  Cookie: Longint;
  rot: IRunningObjectTable;
  hr: HRESULT;
  mk: IMoniker;
  FileIsInUse: IFileIsInUse;
begin
  hr := GetRunningObjectTable(0, rot);
  if SUCCEEDED(hr) then
  begin
    hr := CreateFileMoniker(PChar(AFileName), mk);
    if SUCCEEDED(hr) then
    begin
      FileIsInUse := TFileIsInUseImpl.Create(AFileName);

      hr := rot.Register(ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE or ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT, FileIsInUse, mk, Cookie);
      if hr = CO_E_WRONG_SERVER_IDENTITY then
        hr := rot.Register(ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE, FileIsInUse, mk, Cookie);
      if SUCCEEDED(hr) then
        FRegisteredFiles.Add(AFileName, TRegisteredFile.Create(Cookie, FileIsInUse));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I added registry infos in both `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\MyApp.exe` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{MyGUID}` to indicate `RunAs=Interactive user` so that the first call to `rot.Register` succeeds with `ROTFLAGS_ALLOWANYCLIENT`

However, none of my `TFileIsInUseImpl` methods are ever called.
Overriding `QueryInterface` for it, I discovered that it does get called but only for marshaling related interfaces, never for `IFileIsInUse`.

Looking around I came to the conclusion that something is not initialized the way it should be in my application, but I can't figure out why.
I already tried this:

- Call `CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` instead of the default `CoInitialize(nil)`
- Add `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{MyGuid}\InProcServer32\ThreadingModel=Both`

but nothing helped. Considering that Microsoft's sample is a standalone application, I should be able to replicate what it does.

Can any of you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you registered it in the 32 or 64 Bit registry hive?

Comment: Unless I'm grossly mistaken, HKCR is not virtualized between 32bit and 64bit. 
I went looking into both views via HKLM and they are strictly identical.

Comment: If you see a QI for IMarshal and never get to IFileIsInUse then you do have a marshaling problem.  You ought to see Explorer looking in the Interface registry key for the ProxyStubClsId32.  Use  SysInternals' ProcMon to see that.

Comment: @OBones: HKCR is itself a "virtual" folder (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498) and is primary for 16-Bit applications...(see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475) please register it under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`

Comment: Do you write a EXE or a DLL?

Comment: @OBones: Does the MSDN example work for you?

Comment: The MSDN example works just fine for me, and just like it I'm working on an exe project.
But I finally managed to find out what was wrong in my exe that did not occur in the example one.

Basically, I was calling the Register procedure inside a thread that did not have a message pump. It was properly calling `CoInitialize` but it did not pump any message.

Once I added a message pump to my thread, everything worked just fine. 

Obviously, calling from the main thread of my application works just as well.

Answer (score -1):

If the code was build similar to the MSDN example, then it works as expected. The sample code can be downloaded from the code gallery:

Defect link: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=shellapplication&DownloadId=6773

New link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330722(v=vs.85).aspx
Download from Windows 7 SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330722(v=vs.85).aspx
It is also available in the Windows 7 SDK!